# Div positioned in top visible of their container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going to use an example about what I want to do.
I have a web page with 3 sections.

Each of these 3 sections have two columns.
The left column is a list of elements and the right column is an explanation text based on list elements and dynamically updated.

The problem is that this left column could be long and in small screens when the user scrolls down can't see the text in the right column.

What I like to do is put the right column content in the top of the visible page.
So if we are at the beginning of the section the text is at top of the right column. But when we scroll down the section this text on the right column moves down with the page until the end of the section container.

Does anyone knows some plugin or CSS/Javascript technique to achieve this?
I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap.

I saw similar effect in some webs but I can't find it now.

Thanks.

Comment: show me what have you tried till now... produce some fiddle.

Comment: I don't try anything yet, just thinking how to do it.
I was thinking in put position relative to the div by default.
And capture page position by javascript and when page goes down, change to 'position: absolute' and 'top:0' and when the section goes completely off turn again to position relative.

But I don't like much this approach.

I'll try to create some fiddle example.

Comment: Here is the basic fiddle structure, without any styles about position for the right column:
[http://jsfiddle.net/2cKb4/](http://jsfiddle.net/2cKb4/)

I like to have the div with "TEXT" always visible if the div.section it is visible when you scroll down the page, but stop moving when reach the bottom of the section. and the same behaviour going up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made this script to create the effect I want.

I only want this effect in the first section this is why s only applied to the first one, but is not difficult to propagate all.

http://jsfiddle.net/2cKb4/1/

HTML

```
<div id="section1" class="section">
   <div class="leftCol">
    <ul>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
        <li>element</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
        <div>TEXT line</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.leftCol {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    margin-right: 4%
}

.posFixed {
    position:fixed;
}

.rightCol {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var section = $('#section1');
        if (isTopElementInview(section)) {
            section.find('.rightCol div').removeClass('posFixed');
        } else if (isBottomElementInview(section)) {
            section.find('.rightCol div').addClass('posFixed');
        } else {
            section.find('.rightCol div').removeClass('posFixed');
        }
    });
});

function isTopElementInview(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;

    return elemTop <= docViewBottom && elemTop >= docViewTop;
}

function isBottomElementInview(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemBottom = $(elem).offset().top + $(elem).height();

    return elemBottom <= docViewBottom && elemBottom >= docViewTop;
}
```

What do think about it?
Any suggestion to improve the effect